# Filter & Sorting Not Working for custom column ui_component grid custom column data come from another table through join query in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Filter & Sorting Not Working for custom column course_category_name in ui_component grid & custom column data render from another table through multiple table joins in Magento 2

Our DataProvider code is given below. If anyone has any solution, please give it to me.

collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->categoryCollection = $categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->addFieldStrategies = $addFieldStrategies;
        $this->addFilterStrategies = $addFilterStrategies;
        $this->localeCurrency = $localeCurrency;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->load();
        }

        $categoryResourceModel = $this->categoryCollection->getResource();

        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->join(
            ['xcc' => $categoryResourceModel->getTable('xteam_category_courses')],
            "main_table.course_id = xcc.course_id",
            ['xcc.course_category_id']
        )->join(
            ['xccat' => $categoryResourceModel->getTable('xteam_course_categories')],
            'xcc.course_category_id = xccat.course_category_id',
            [
                'course_category_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT xcc.course_category_id ORDER BY xcc.course_category_id)'),
                'course_category_name' => new Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT xccat.course_category_name ORDER BY xcc.course_category_id)')
            ]
        )->group('main_table.course_id');

        $items = $this->getCollection()->getData();

        // echo ""; print_r($items->getData()); exit;

        return [
            'totalRecords' => $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
            'items' => array_values($items),
        ];
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for Filter & Sorting for custom column ui_component grid.

We need to add this code in DataProvider File then filter & sorting working perfect.

```
public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
{
    if (isset($this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()])) {
        $this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()]
            ->addFilter(
                $this->getCollection(),
                $filter->getField(),
                [$filter->getConditionType() =>
                 $filter->getValue()]
            );
    } else {
        parent::addFilter($filter);
    }
}


public function addField($field, $alias = null)
{
    if (isset($this->addFieldStrategies[$field])) {
        $this->addFieldStrategies[$field]->addField(
        $this->getCollection(), $field, $alias);
    } else {
        parent::addField($field, $alias);
    }
}
```